# React DatePicker no working in next.js because of css import

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, next.js

I'm trying to use [react-date-picker](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker) in a `next.js` project.

I started with first installing the package: `npm install react-date-picker`

Then in my `_app.js` file I've added:

```
import "react-date-picker/dist/DatePicker.css";
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
```

Then in one of my custom components I'm trying to use the date picker:

```
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

const [dateValue,setDateValue] = useState(new Date());

<DatePicker value={dateValue} onChange={setDateValue} />
```

When I run the app and try to navigate to the page that contains the date picker i get the following error:
[image]

I've followed the documentation but I'm still getting an error and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: btw the DatePicker is used inside an exported function,I just tried to simplify my question

Comment: Please checkout the issue here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19166#discussion-32218

Answer (score 6):

this package is not working for me too so I found the same package but with a different way of installation:

npm install react-datepicker

then the useage will be like this :
add this line in your component :

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
const Example = () => {
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
return (
<DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date:Date) => setStartDate(date)}
 );
 };
```

and style import will be added at your _app file :

```
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
```

here is the resource [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker)

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer - thanks from the future! the npm installation documentation you linked to is more robust than the project website at https://reactdatepicker.com

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Nextjs. Replace your DateTimePicker `import` by these:

```
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker/dist/entry.nostyle'; 
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css'; 
import 'react-clock/dist/Clock.css'; 
import 'react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.css';
```

Found it [here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-datetime-picker/issues/143#issuecomment-853834044)

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsKyh.png)

Next.js do not allow components from node_modules to import styles. You'll need to custom styling.

https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker#custom-styling

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).